# subsetting in data.table - by argument

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I have this R code used to manipulate a `data.table` but I don't understand what does the `by` do:

```
dt = cli[(aaa==0) & bbb==0,    
         .(a1, a2="abc", a3=aaa,),    
         by=c("b1","b2")
        ]
```

If I understand correctly it creates a new `data.table` selecting the rows of `cli` where the columns `aaa` and `bbb` are both equal zero, and columns `a1`, a new column `a2` always equal to `"abc"` and renames column `aaa` as `a3`.

I see that the new `data.table` carries also the columns in `c("b1","b2")` but I don't undestand if there's some operation behind them, otherwise why not listing them in the `.(...)` part?

With and without the `by` argument I obtain the same number of rows.

**EDIT**: I'm including a simplified example:

```
in1

    ID DIG  VAR1  VAR2
1: 230  68  TRUE  TRUE
2: 232   0 FALSE  TRUE
3: 236  81  TRUE FALSE
4: 239  92  TRUE FALSE
5: 243   0 FALSE  TRUE
6: 245  45  TRUE  TRUE

in1[(DIG<80),.(ID)]

    ID
1: 230
2: 232
3: 243
4: 245

in1[(DIG<80),.(ID), by=c('VAR1','VAR2')]

    VAR1 VAR2  ID
1:  TRUE TRUE 230
2:  TRUE TRUE 245
3: FALSE TRUE 232
4: FALSE TRUE 243
```

It seems to me that the `by` part is just changing the order of the selection. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

`by` is performing the operations by all groups within columns `b1` and `b2`. Lets say column `b1` has two levels (values) `0` and `1`, using `by="b1"` the new data.table will have two rows corresponding to operation performed at `b1==0` and separately `b1==2`. If you omit `by` then the operation will be applied jointly across all values of `b1`. If this is still not clear i recommend you compare the output with and without including `by=c("b1","b2")`. You should see only one row without it. With `by=c("b1","b2")` the number of rows of the output `data.table` corresponds to the unique number of values of both `b1` and `b2`.

Comment: In this case which is the operation? Is it selecting the distinct combinations of values in `c("b1","b2")` that satisfy `(aaa==0) & bbb==0`? What puzzles me is that I obtain the same number of rows with and without the by argument

Comment: The operation is `(aaa==0) & bbb==0` and it is being performed on all unique combinations of values of `b1` and `b2`. I think the same rows with or without might be due to some special feature of the data. A reproducible example would be helpful to getting to the bottom of that.

Comment: if you substituted `(aaa==0) & bbb==0, .(a1, a2="abc", a3=aaa,)`, with something like `mean(aaa)`, then the number of rows would be different with and without `by`

Comment: It seems to me that it's just changing the order of the rows by the combinations of columns listed in `by`. With and without it the selection is the same. And it's not selecting only the rows with unique values of the variables in `by`.